# Hive is unable to read data from HDFS in HDP 3.x

Tags: hive, hive-serde

Hiveserver2 is unable to read the HDFS data. I have built the table on top of HDFS.

These are the table properties which I have tried to resolve the problem, none of them are working perfectly in HDP 3.x

1. Tried both Internal and External tables
2. Stored as ORC
3. 777 permission recursively for all the folders
4. Executing the table as the same owner of the table
5. Transnational true (internal table only)
6. Orc compress zlib
7. Msck repair executed successfully. Showing partition values and size of the folders are same as in prod
8. Partitioned and Bucketed

`` CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `machine_data`(`ids` string,`delta` 
    string,`locatio` string,`time_data` string,`valid` boolean,`measure` 
    string,`val` float
 ) 
 PARTITIONED BY (`nodename` string) 
 CLUSTERED BY (delta) INTO 53 BUCKETS 
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
; ``

I have moved the data from Server A to Server B and Server C to HDFS and built a table on top of HDFS data. All the three servers are in HDP 3.1. Server A it is production server which is working fine from initial setup. Moved the data to dev and test server respectively.

Server B is test server which seems to be working without any change next day.

Server C is Dev server is not at all working after three days.

HS2 configs are compared. Almost same for across the servers

It is really strange to handle these type of scenario.

Comment: when you say you are not able to read, what happens? does it give error ? `0 records` or something else ?

Comment: Yes . It is completely zero records . I'm unable to figure out the solution so far .